# Why do the textures for these two very similar objects differ so much?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I have two road models that are largely the same (one being slightly different) yet when I apply the shader system along with my texture they differ quite a bit. The road texture on the right is what I want my road on the left to look like.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Blend File: https://blend-exchange.com/b/epvZVPZ6

Answer (score -1):

I simply had to align the two objects, data transfer then vertex paint and then do a few touch-ups and it was completely fixed. For some reason Blender removed the vertex paint from my object without me noticing.